# Acting on the existence or non-existence of a key using JQ

Tags: json, jq

I have a JSON file containing objects that are similar to each other, but not identical.  All objects have a main identifier, but other keys may or may not exist within an object.

My question:  for a given key in an object, how do I print out the value if it exists, and something like "NA" if it does not, printing the original name of the key either way?

Sample input:

```
  {
      "DBInstances": [
          {
              "Identifier": 101,
              "foo": "some_value",
              "bar": 60,
              "Model": "A"
          },
          {
              "Identifier": 102,
              "foo": "some_value",
              "Model": "B"
          }
      ]
  }
```

Desired output:

```
          {
              "Identifier": 101,
              "foo": "some_value",
              "bar": 60,
              "Model": "A"
          },
          {
              "Identifier": 102,
              "foo": "some_value",
              "bar": "NA",
              "Model": "B"
          }
```

I created a function that works (partly) for non-existence, but not at all for existence:

```
  def exist(element):
     if (has( element ) == true)
     then { element: "true" }
     else { element: "NA" }
     end;
```

when I call it with:

```
 exist( "bar" )
```

The "existence" part is completely wrong in that JQ prints "element" and "true" rather than the original key name and value.

For the "non-existence" part, JQ prints "NA" just fine, but "element" instead of the original key name.

I'm working with JQ 1.3.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's the correct way to write your "exist" definition:

```
def exist(element):
  if has( element )
  then { (element): .[element] }
  else { (element): "NA" }
  end;
```

This has been tested with jq 1.3 but please try to upgrade to a more recent version.

In practice, one is more likely to use an idiom such as this:

```
if has(element) then . else .[element] = "NA" end
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is another solution which uses [update assignment |=](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#Update-assignment:|=)

```
   .DBInstances[] | .bar |= if .==null then "NA" else . end
```